# Springdoc Open API UI - BaseLayout doesn't works

Tags: spring, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui, springdoc-ui

I went through: https://springdoc.org/springdoc-properties.html#springdoc-openapi-core-properties before raisng the question, but look like things are not working.

I want to use BaseLayout and also wanted to change the theme of the Open API Specification response as its in black.

I am using `Spring Boot v2.2.2.RELEASE` and `springdoc-openapi-ui V1.2.30`.

```
# Open API Configurations
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui-ref.html
springdoc.swagger-ui.display-request-duration=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.tagsSorter=alpha
springdoc.swagger-ui.doc-expansion=no
springdoc.swagger-ui.layout=BaseLayout
```

Even after putting the above configurations, default configuration is not taking into an effect.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed since v1.2.31:

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/536